# use ^ inside of [] as start of line

Tags: regular-expressions

I'd like to remove the following two comments line,

```
## comments 1 
f <- function() {
  ## comments 2 
}
```

I use `(search-forward-regexp "^[[:space:]]+##")` to search for  "  ##" (the line start with 2 indentation whitespaces followed by ##) and `(search-forward-regexp "^##")` to search for the line that starts with `##`.

How can I combine them into one line of script like below?

```el
(search-forward-regexp "[[:space:]+\|^]##")
```

This is obvious wrong, according to http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression; `^` inside of `[ ]` means negate.

Comment: @kaushalmodi If a question presents an ambiguity or contradiction, shouldn't we ask the OP how to resolve it, instead of arbitrarily picking one interpretation and edit the other one out? The latter solution risks defacing the question, and encourage people in posting unhelpful answers.

Comment: @T.Verron Sure, the OP should comment on this. This was the original content in the question: *I use `(search-forward-regexp "[[:space:]]+##")` to search for "   ## ", the line start with 2 indentation whitespaces followed by ## and 
`(search-forward-regexp "^##")` to search for the line that starts with ##*. I removed the specification about "line start with 2 indentation" because he was referring to that in his example snippet and also his regex snippet "[[:space:]]+##" did not have a strict limitation on number of spaces.

Comment: @T.Verron Hi, I agree with your opinion, pointing out the ambiguity/contraction, and asking the OP to redefine the question can improve the answers greatly. as OP, I think it's important.  It may, however, result few more around of editing and cost more time of the reviewer than just editing by himself or herself because the OP can be confused easily.  Thanks for warm heart people in this community, I got three questions so far which not only can solve the problem, but also expand my knowledge.

Comment: @yi.tang.uni II understand how it can be confusing, especially given that the ambiguity was not explicitely framed in comments under the question, but only in the answers. As the OP, maybe you can resolve it now, though : do you want to match either 0, or 1 or more spaces (in which case you can rollback my last edit), or do you want to match 0, or 2 or more spaces?

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
(search-forward-regexp "^\\(^\\|[[:space:]]+\\)##")
```

That is, create a group (between `\\(` and `\\)`) with two alternatives, separated by `\\|`, one of them being `^` and the other being `[[:space:]]+`.

By the way, `[[:space:]]+` searches for one or more whitespace characters.  If you want two or more, use `[[:space:]]\\{2,\\}`.

Comment: Note that the `^` in the group can be omitted, matching the empty string should be enough. Then it can be simplified in `\\([[:space:]]+\\)\\?`. Now either the OP really wants 2 spaces, in which case he will indeed have to change the `+`, or `+` (1 or more) is really what he wants, and then the regexp can again be simplified into `[[:space:]]*`.

Comment: @T.Verron I don't think the group is needed at all here. If the alternatives are either one or more spaces, or no spaces, the * operator covers everything.

Comment: @Tyler: The question was edited (not by the OP). The OP said that he wants to match "2 tabulations or whitespace, or none", hence the `\\{2,\\}`. In this case the group is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer gives you a good regexp for your problem, I just want to add a bit more information about what seems to be your confusion.

The square brackets syntax `[...]` means *one of any of the characters listed in the brackets*. As such, you can not use any regular expression in it. As a side-note, this is why `^` can have a different syntax in this context, otherwise that would create an unresolvable ambiguity for the regexp engine.

What you are looking for is a syntax for *any string matching regexp1 OR regexp 2*, which is the logical `\\|`, within a group.

Examples

```
\\(a\\|b\\)   # a or b, equivalent to [ab]
\\(aa\\|bb\\) # aa or bb, no easy equivalent
\\(aa\\|\\)   # aa or nothing, equivalent to \\(aa\\)\\?
```

So indeed, for your problem:

```
^\\(\\|[[:blank:]]\\{2,\\}\\)##
```

should match what you want: 0, 2 or more whitespace characters at the beginning of a line, followed by two `#`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```
(search-forward-regexp "^[[:space:]]*##")
```

This matches the beginning of a line (`^`) followed by 0 or more spaces (`[[:space:]]*`) followed by two hashes (`##`). Thus, it matches both lines that start with `##`, as well as those that have any number of spaces before the `##`.